# Rails Console não carrega os métodos e classes da minha aplicação, por que?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

Eu tenho um model chamado Person, quando abro o Rails Console e tento atribuir-lo à uma variável qualquer, recebo isso:

```
user.localapp (test) $ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0) (Ruby 2.2.0)
localapp> a = person.first
NameError: undefined local variable or method `person' for main:Object
from (irb):1
```

Alguém sabe porque?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Person` (primeira letra maiúscula) ao invés de `person` (primeira letra minúscula)

```
a = Person.first
```

Comment: Vlw deu certinho!

Answer (score 2):

`person` é uma variável que não existe. Você tem de chamar o método da classe:

```
person = Person.first
```

Isso vai te trazer a primeira `Person` do seu banco de dados.

Comment: Vlw deu certinho!